# How to delete a word in a string if it appears more than once in the same line?

Tags: python

I have a list of words in a txt file, each one in a line with its definition next to them. However, the definition sometimes gives a sentence using the word. I want to replace that word repeated in the example with the symbol ~. How could I do this with Python?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: That is simple, in 4 steps: 1. read the file, line by line; 2. parse the line, i.e. extract the word and the definition; 3. detect the word in the definition and make a substitution; 4. write the modified lines into file. Which of these steps have you done so far, which one are you having problems with?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer for solving your problem.

Comment: I was not sure about what would be the best way to structure the program, but thanks zvone and sak, I could do it thanks to your advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is my example of replacing every instance of a word in a sentence with another character...

```
>>> my_string = "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"
>>> search_word = "the"
>>> replacement_symbol = "~"
>>> my_string.replace(search_word, replacement_symbol)
'~ quick brown fox jumped over ~ lazy dog'
```

Obviously this doesn't cover loading in the file, reading it line by line and omitting the first instance of the word... Lets extend it a little.

words.txt

```
fox the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
the the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
jumped the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
```

And to read this, strip the first word and then replace that word in the rest of the line...

```
with open('words.txt') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        line = line.strip()
        search_term = line.split(' ')[0]
        sentence = ' '.join(line.split(' ')[1:])
        sentence = sentence.replace(search_term, '~')
        line = '%s %s' % (search_term, sentence)
        print(line)
```

and the output...

```
fox the quick brown ~ jumped over the lazy dog
the ~ quick brown fox jumped over ~ lazy dog
jumped the quick brown fox ~ over the lazy dog
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the word and definition is separated by #:

```
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    for line in f:
        myword,mydefinition=line.split("#") 

        if myword in mydefinition
            mydefinition.replace(myword, "~")
```